# When do UDP multicast streams/frames diffuse?

Tags: switch, multicast, udp

Please consider my network topology:

```
(Machine A0) --- [Switch A] ============ [Switch B] --- (Machine B0)

                                             |

                                             |
                                        (Machine B1)
```

As you could observe `Machine A0` is physically connected to `switch A` (respectively `machines B0,B1` are physically connected to `switch B`). `Switches A and B` are connected directly to each other.

`Machine A0` multicasts a message `m`.

Should m be dulplicated directly on `machine A0`, on `switch A` or on `switch B`?

Comment: Let me answer the question with a question:  how would machine A0 "know" how many receivers there are, and therefore how many duplicates to make of the packet?  Then ask yourself the same question of switch A and B.

Comment: @Ron Let me continue with a question: Should a node that multicasts over UDP know the number of receivers? As far as I know No! Please correct me should I am wrong.

Comment: You are right -- the sender doesn't know.  So it can't be the one duplicating packets

Comment: you are right. So, Switch B will duplicate it. Thank you again @Ron

Comment: The other things to keep in mind are what type of switches are they and are they doing anything like igmp snooping.

Comment: @Doon whether they run IGMP snooping or not has no bearing on the question

Comment: @Ron, would you please explain why, i am confused about IGMP snooping too.

Comment: Whether IGMP snooping is on or off, B will still duplicate the packets. Snooping will make B more efficient and only forward MC packets out of ports it hears receivers on.

Comment: So why don't you write an answer?

Comment: Could the question be clarified to indicate this is L2 multicast only, and neither switch A or B are routing any of this multicast traffic?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

In the absences of a feature like IGMP snooping, a L2 device will flood a copy of the frame out every active interface besides the one on which it was received. In your example, this means that both *SwA* and *SwB* will send the multicast traffic out every one of their active ports besides the receiving port.

IGMP snooping is a feature on most modern enterprise switches which allows the switch to learn which devices are joined to which multicast groups and only forward the frame to those destination ports. In your example (assuming both *MachineB0* and *MachineB1* had joined the multicast group and are the only devices besides *MachineA0* to do so), *SwA* would send a copy to *SwB* and *SwB* will send a copy out the ports going to *MachineB0* and *MachineB1*. The frame would not be sent out any other active ports.

Answer (score -1):

The default behavior for a Layer 2 switch is to forward all multicast traffic to every port that belongs to the destination LAN on the switch.

IP multicast is not in play unless there is a router (layer 3 device) between these end machines.  So, we are speaking here of Ethernet frames (not IP packets).